# DataGrid with internal margins in a style has wrong initial size, sorts itself out on resizing the window

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid containing a number of DataGridTemplateColumns. One of these has Width="*" and the rest have Width="Auto". Most just contain a TextBox. I want a margin on each side of each element, so in the style assigned to the TextBox I had Margin="10,1". What I observed was that the initial width of the DataGrid would be too wide. If the window was manually made thinner, the DataGrid would also go thinner- but maintaining the overwidth. If the window was made larger, the DataGrid would not get wider until its width was correct, and from then on resizing would work correctly.

If I remove the margin from the style and place it explicitly in the TextBox of each column then everything works as expected, so my problem is solved. But I'd still like to know what's going on since if I want to change those margins it'll be far better to have one style to change. Is this some odd bug in the DataGrid or something I'm not understanding correctly?

The DataGrid is nested inside some other items, but because the fix is so trivial it makes me think the DataGrid and styles are the only significant factors.

Columns look like this;

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="SKUColumn"
            Header="SKU" 
            Width="Auto">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox x:Name="skuText"
                     Text="{Binding Path=SKU, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                     Style="{StaticResource textBodyCell}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and textBodyCell looks like this;

```
<Style x:Key="textBodyCell" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="{StaticResource bodySize}" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
    <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridCellTextBox}"/>

</Style>
```

where DataGridCellTextBox is

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DataGridCellTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Foreground="{StaticResource DataGridUnSelectedRowForeground}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="{StaticResource DataGridSelectedRowForeground}" />
        </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="{StaticResource DataGridUnSelectedRowForeground}" />
        </DataTrigger>          

        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```